Why do the opposite of skillful virtues result in remorse?

"Skillful virtues have freedom from remorse as their purpose,
Ananda, and freedom from remorse as their reward."
AN 11.1


It is natural that non-regret arises in a virtuous
person, one whose behavior is virtuous.
AN 10.2

What is the basis for defining skillful virtues, that would result in freedom from remorse?
The Abrahamic religions depend on God to define what is right and wrong.
The Buddhist suttas define skillful virtues based on "freedom from remorse".
The precepts like killing, stealing, adultery and lying result in remorse. Why do they result in remorse?
I've seen vague explanations based on laws of karma or kamma niyama (Dhp 127), natural laws or principles ("this law of nature persists, this regularity of natural principles, this invariance of natural principles") based on AN 3.136 or SN 12.20, the Golden Rule ("don't do unto others what you don't want others to do unto you") based on Ud 5.1, and linking to the three poisons.
However, I have not seen suttas that definitively provide a cause for remorse.
Please support with sutta references, as far as possible.

@blue_ego Remorse and regret is unskillful. Fear and shame of evil is skillful. One is regarding past. The other regarding future.

I think both remorse (a subset of guilt and targets our behaviour) and shame (which targets our character weaknesses) help trigger reflections into our past actions. This begins an investigation and understanding of not only what was wrong but more importantly why. The deeper we penetrated the root causes for our behaviour and the associated harm, the less chance of recidivism.

regret is logical, one feels remorse, they ponder 'if only...' :(

AN 4.121 gives us the mundane truth of fear:

“Mendicants, there are these four fears. What four? The fears of
guilt, shame, punishment, and going to a bad place.

That was the discourse related to this excerpt from a lecture:

In the Anguttara Nikaya there is a reference to four types of fears:
Fear of self-reproach (attaanuvaada bhaya), fear of others' reproach
(paraanuvaada bhaya), fear of punishment (da.n.da bhaya) and fear of
lower worlds (duggati bhaya). In this context these fears have a good
effect on the person: "he abandons evil," and "develops the practice
of good."


Yes, even someone with wrong view, who don't believe in other world and consequences to one's actions, knows there's shame and punishment about their inappropriate actions.

it should be noted this is worry too, a hindrance..it disturbs calm, a requisite for awakening, thus it makes sense from a Buddhist perspective

I won't accept my own answer.
I've found the following suttas (MN 61 and MN 88) that indirectly answer the question.
These suttas state that unskillful deeds by body, speech and mind, hurts myself, hurts others or hurts both, is blameworthy (i.e. invites criticism from others), and has suffering as its outcome and its result.
Although these suttas do not talk about regret or remorse, I would say, one would regret performing actions by body, speech and mind that brings suffering to oneself and/or others. It goes back to the first noble truth, that there is suffering. And we don't want suffering.
So, using this definition, we can derive virtues and the opposite of virtues.
This commentary by Ven. Sujato for MN 88 is very apt:

“Unskillful behavior.” “Unskillful” (akusala) is an unwholesome
quality of the mind, so this is the psychological dimension of
immorality. What is unskillful is that which leads to the result
opposite to that desired: we want happiness, but it leads to
suffering.

Quotes from MN 61, followed by MN 88:

“In the same way, deeds of body, speech, and mind should be done only
after repeated checking.
When you want to act with the body, you should check on that same
deed: ‘Does this act with the body that I want to do lead to hurting
myself, hurting others, or hurting both? Is it unskillful, with
suffering as its outcome and result?’ If, while checking in this way,
you know: ‘This act with the body that I want to do leads to hurting
myself, hurting others, or hurting both. It’s unskillful, with
suffering as its outcome and result.’ To the best of your ability,
Rāhula, you should not do such a deed. But if, while checking in this
way, you know: ‘This act with the body that I want to do doesn’t lead
to hurting myself, hurting others, or hurting both. It’s skillful,
with happiness as its outcome and result.’ Then, Rāhula, you should do
such a deed.
While you are acting with the body, you should check on that same act:
‘Does this act with the body that I am doing lead to hurting myself,
hurting others, or hurting both? Is it unskillful, with suffering as
its outcome and result?’ If, while checking in this way, you know:
‘This act with the body that I am doing leads to hurting myself,
hurting others, or hurting both. It’s unskillful, with suffering as
its outcome and result.’ Then, Rāhula, you should desist from such a
deed. But if, while checking in this way, you know: ‘This act with the
body that I am doing doesn’t lead to hurting myself, hurting others,
or hurting both. It’s skillful, with happiness as its outcome and
result.’ Then, Rāhula, you should continue doing such a deed.
After you have acted with the body, you should check on that same act:
‘Does this act with the body that I have done lead to hurting myself,
hurting others, or hurting both? Is it unskillful, with suffering as
its outcome and result?’ If, while checking in this way, you know:
‘This act with the body that I have done leads to hurting myself,
hurting others, or hurting both. It’s unskillful, with suffering as
its outcome and result.’ Then, Rāhula, you should confess, reveal, and
clarify such a deed to the Teacher or a sensible spiritual companion.
And having revealed it you should restrain yourself in future. But if,
while checking in this way, you know: ‘This act with the body that I
have done doesn’t lead to hurting myself, hurting others, or hurting
both. It’s skillful, with happiness as its outcome and result.’ Then,
Rāhula, you should live in rapture and joy because of this, training
day and night in skillful qualities.
When you want to act with speech, you should check on that same deed:
‘Does this act of speech that I want to do lead to hurting myself,
hurting others, or hurting both? …’ …
If, while checking in this way, you know: ‘This act of speech that I
have done leads to hurting myself, hurting others, or hurting both.
It’s unskillful, with suffering as its outcome and result.’ Then,
Rāhula, you should confess, reveal, and clarify such a deed to the
Teacher or a sensible spiritual companion. And having revealed it you
should restrain yourself in future. But if, while checking in this
way, you know: ‘This act of speech that I have done doesn’t lead to
hurting myself, hurting others, or hurting both. It’s skillful, with
happiness as its outcome and result.’ Then, Rāhula, you should live in
rapture and joy because of this, training day and night in skillful
qualities.
When you want to act with the mind, you should check on that same
deed: ‘Does this act of mind that I want to do lead to hurting myself,
hurting others, or hurting both? …’ …
If, while checking in this way, you know: ‘This act of mind that I
have done leads to hurting myself, hurting others, or hurting both.
It’s unskillful, with suffering as its outcome and result.’ Then,
Rāhula, you should be horrified, repelled, and disgusted by that deed.
And being repelled, you should restrain yourself in future. But if,
while checking in this way, you know: ‘This act with the mind that I
have done doesn’t lead to hurting myself, hurting others, or hurting
both. It’s skillful, with happiness as its outcome and result.’ Then,
Rāhula, you should live in rapture and joy because of this, training
day and night in skillful qualities.
All the ascetics and brahmins of the past, future, and present who
purify their physical, verbal, and mental actions do so after
repeatedly checking. So Rāhula, you should train yourself like this:
‘I will purify my physical, verbal, and mental actions after
repeatedly checking.’”
MN 61


But Honorable Ānanda, what kind of bodily behavior is faulted by
sensible ascetics and brahmins?” This passage describes bad actions
from five perspectives, showing that the Buddha’s analysis of morality
was not based on a single factor.

Commentary by Ven. Sujato:
“Unskillful behavior.” “Unskillful” (akusala) is an unwholesome
quality of the mind, so this is the psychological dimension of
immorality. What is unskillful is that which leads to the result
opposite to that desired: we want happiness, but it leads to
suffering.

“But what kind of bodily behavior is unskillful?”

Commentary by Ven. Sujato:
“Blameworthy behavior.” “Blameworthy” (sāvajja) behavior is that which
makes one liable to criticism by others. This is the social dimension
of immorality.

“But what kind of bodily behavior is blameworthy?”

Commentary by Ven. Sujato:
“Hurtful behavior.” “Hurtful” (sabyābajjha) refers to the fact that
bad conduct is characterized by hurtful affliction both in its action
and its consequences.

“But what kind of bodily behavior is hurtful?”

Commentary by Ven. Sujato:
“Behavior that results in suffering.” “Results in suffering”
(dukkhavipāka) through painful kammic consequences in this life or the
future.

“But what kind of bodily behavior results in suffering?”
“Bodily behavior that leads to hurting yourself, hurting others, and
hurting both, Bad conduct does not just affect oneself, but
reverberates in space, by harming others, and in time, by promoting
the growth of even more unskillful qualities.and which makes
unskillful qualities grow while skillful qualities decline. That kind
of bodily behavior is faulted by sensible ascetics and brahmins.”
“But what kind of verbal behavior … mental behavior is faulted by
sensible ascetics and brahmins?” …
“Mental behavior that leads to hurting yourself, hurting others, and
hurting both, and which makes unskillful qualities grow while skillful
qualities decline. That kind of mental behavior is faulted by sensible
ascetics and brahmins.”
“Sir, does the Buddha praise giving up all these unskillful things?”
“Great king, the Realized One has given up all unskillful things and
possesses skillful things.”
MN 88


AN 10.1 & 2 and AN 11.1 & 2 use the term vippaṭisāro.

vippaṭisāra
masc. remorse; regret; lit. remembering back negatively [vi + pati +
√sar + *a]

'Vippaṭisāra' is often used together with 'kukkuccaṁ' (which is included in the five hindrances):

“I hope you don’t have any remorse or regret?”
“Kacci te, vakkali, na kiñci kukkuccaṁ, na koci vippaṭisāro”
SN 22.87

The Peṭakopadesa, a commentary in the Khuddaka Nikāya, says:

Tassa ganthitā kilesā āsavanti. Kiñci pana vuccati vippaṭisāro. Ye
vippaṭisārā te anusayā. Tattha abhijjhākāyaganthena kāmāsavo,
byāpādakāyaganthena bhavāsavo, parāmāsakāyaganthena diṭṭhāsavo, idaṁ
saccābhinivesakāyaganthena avijjāsavo.
When bound/caught/enslaved (ganthitā) to defilements that flow out; this is called remorse (vippaṭisāro).
This remorse is from underlying tendencies. Herein, the outflow of
sensual desire is due to the group [of aggregates]-bind of covetousness, the outflow
of becoming is due to the group-bind of ill will, the outflow of views
is due to the group-bind of misapprehension, and the outflow of
ignorance is due to the group-bind of insistence that this is truth.
Pe 9 (rough amended translation by DD)


Gathita adjective tied, bound, fettered; enslaved, bound to greedy
for, intoxicated with (c. loc.)

The Peṭakopadesa, above, appears to refer to different types of remorse. For example. possibly the Peṭakopadesa is suggesting:

Remorse due to covetousness (which causes sensual desire), for example, remorse because you don't have enough money & luxuries to impress your rich friends.

Remorse due to ill-will (which causes becoming), for example, remorse because of a painful situation inflicted upon oneself or upon another.

Remorse due to misapprehension (which causes views), for example, remorse of making a fool out of yourself because you misconstrued the nature of a person you interrelated with in a certain unsuitable manner.

Remorse due to insistence (which causes ignorance to arise), for example, remorse due to insisting on a plan that goes terribly wrong.


In summary, the word 'vippaṭisāro' translated as 'remorse' or 'regret' literally means 'to remember back in a negative manner'. This 'remembering back' obviously arises from the feeling of pain, unhappiness, trouble or difficulty that has become a bondage.
In other words, it appears 'vippaṭisāro' is not a natural automatic result of kamma (i.e., Dhamma Nikaya). Instead, it appears 'vippaṭisāro' refers to a product of rumination/over-thinking; a craving for a past action & its results to be otherwise. Refer to AN 3.99 about different contrasting responses to the same act of kamma.
In conclusion, killing, stealing, adultery and lying can result in remorse because these actions can result in imprisonment, PTSD, loss of wealth, loss of trust & friends, etc.

So, your conclusion is that non-virtue results in remorse, due to the negative consequences of karma.

I think the conclusion may be going too far, or that I've misunderstood -- it implies that one might be delighted to get away with a crime, unpunished, like a psychopath. I suppose the Buddhist doctrine is not (only) about mundane consequence but about some (cause and) effect on the mind.

No. Remorse certainly does not apply to unpunished asuras & animals. Obviously particularly the current world is saturated with asura & animals; such as those that deny a genocide is currently occurring. The Dhamma is mostly for devas & humans. The Dhamma is not for all. This comment is going too far when inferring  some lawful (cause and) effect on the mind. While all unwholesome actions have the potential for remorse due to external punishment, not all bad actions inherently result in remorse. The answer explicitly said remorse is not Dhamma-Niyama, referring to AN 3.99.

It is very simple. Good people do not steal , lie , kill or do adultery. It is a sanskar of good people. Such a mindset brings joy and peace but if the sankhara gets violated then there is a feeling of remorse. The feeling of happiness or joy is based on the understanding of Truth.The Truth is all living creatures are suffering or are going to suffer. This mindset alone guarantees joy and peace. But if you do the opposite of what Truth demands then happiness collapses as it was conditionally achieved.
The point to be noted here is that all sankharas are impermanent. Therefore do not build your happiness on any sankharas.
Buddha asks his followers to give up all attachments so that we can rise above the conditioning of good and bad.

How can u call it opposite…another dimension is not exactly opposite

Good people when do bad things then bad is the opposite of good. For good people bad actions bring grief. For bad people bad actions do not bring grief. Definition of good is derived from the adherence to Truth. @blue_ego

Because you naturally feel bad when you do something wrong. Unless you don't have a conscience, and don't care about others, or don't even care about ruining yourself. For normal people, small mistakes make you feel a little stupid or regretful, and major mistakes will mess you up for life, every time you think about it. It's an important way we learn about what's good and bad, skillful and unskillful. In that way, the former leads to its own reward, and the latter, its own punishment, like the carrot and the stick. And that doesn't even take into account the consequences from others, like getting the reputation of being untrustworthy, or going to jail.
The other reason, which is not necessarily immediately experienced or apparent, but rather belief based, is rebirth and karma, and those are part of right view. That's why it's said wrong view leads to rebirth in the lower planes, because if you think you can do whatever you want and never have to pay the price, then there's nothing to stop evil people from running amok, or middle of the road people from giving free rein to their worse impulses.

And how is right view the forerunner? One discerns wrong resolve as wrong resolve, and right resolve as right resolve. This is one's right view. And what is wrong resolve? Being resolved on sensuality, on ill will, on harmfulness.  ...
And what is wrong speech? Lying, divisive tale-bearing, abusive speech, & idle chatter.  ...
And what is wrong action? Killing, taking what is not given, illicit sex.  ...
And what is wrong livelihood? Scheming, persuading, hinting, belittling, & pursuing gain with gain. -MN 117
 
The Blessed One said, "Monks, ignorance is the leader in the attainment of unskillful qualities, followed by lack of conscience & lack of concern. In an unknowledgeable person, immersed in ignorance, wrong view arises. In one of wrong view, wrong resolve arises. In one of wrong resolve, wrong speech... In one of wrong speech, wrong action... In one of wrong action, wrong livelihood... In one of wrong livelihood, wrong effort... In one of wrong effort, wrong mindfulness... In one of wrong mindfulness, wrong concentration arises. -SN 45.1

Aristotle said "I have gained this by philosophy: that I do without being commanded, what others do only from fear of the law."

Why is it translated "remorse"?
IMO the word remorse is inevitably connected with "I" -- for example I might "regret" something you do, but by definition not feel "remorse" about it -- "remorse" is about what "I" do.
Morality too is connected with a sense of "I" -- for example we're taught to be generous instead of selfish.
I think commentary says that being generous (for example) helps to alleviate egocentricity (and I suppose that various forms of selfishness are inherent too in breaking the various precepts for example).
And I think that "self" and a sense of self is connected with "suffering" -- that isn't explicit in the first sutta (possibly implicit, in "death" etc.), but the very next (second) sutta is about the self.
So I think they're all related and the relationship is egocentricity -- remorse, self, virtue, suffering.
The relationships between those might seem complicated, tenuous or indirect, a bit of a "tangle" or thicket, but still.
Where a unvirtuous action might result in "Oh I was so wrong!", a virtuous one might be "No problem!"

I'd add three observations that aren't directly related to the question:

"Recollection of virtue" is one the standard objects of meditation
Perhaps "virtue" is omnipresent, in the sense that a monk might always "have" virtue, even when they don't "have" material possessions (to rejoice them)
Virtue or the absence of remorse might be the only good thing e.g., "Well those were terrible/unfortunate circumstances, but at least I behaved well -- and can have done no better so no cause for remorse")


I am approaching this question from a different angle. Why don’t unskillful actions result in remorse, guilt or shame? Hopefully, this will shed light on why, sometimes, things don't happen as expected i.e. bad or harmful actions resulting in guilt (remorse) and shame.
A study on psychopathy and recidivism indicated that psychopaths are three times more likely to reoffend than non-psychopaths. The conventional wisdom is that psychopaths (to a lesser extent their cousins, the sociopaths) displayed little or no regrets, remorse, guilt or shame in their behaviours. Surprisingly, a study on deficits in affective responsiveness in psychopaths seems to indicate that they are capable of retrospective regrets with regards to poor outcomes. However, they appeared not to be able to utilize prospective regret signals to adjust their decision-making. Oftentimes, this appeared in highly risky decision-making that is associated with poor counterfactual thinking. To summarize, this inability to imagine that they or others would or could be hurt or harm as a result of their actions (aka poor counterfactual thinking) thus triggering regret, remorse and guilt ultimately meant that they are unable to stop or prevent their own behaviour.
Similarly, a negative correlation is shown between psychopathy and the degree of guilt sensitivity in one study. However, it is unknown if psychopathy is the cause of diminished sensitivity to guilt, shame and remorse or is psychopathy the result of this reduced sensitivity instead. If it is the former then a possible approach is to emphasize proper social etiquette or behaviour from young. If it is the latter, maybe inculcating a proper sense of shame and a willingness to admit guilt when wrong in children could be a worthy consideration. Another approach to be considered is to strengthen counterfactual thinking which appeared to be the technique advised by the Buddha to the young Rahula in MN61 as mentioned in the answer by @ruben2020.
Lastly, it should be stressed that it is important to differentiate between cases of psychopathy and psychopathology (i.e. mental illness). As a research had indicated that inducing shame or remorse may result in poorer treatment outcome in cases of psychopathology.

In Buddhist thought, the concept of skillful virtues, or "kusala," refers to actions, thoughts, and intentions that lead to positive outcomes, mental clarity, and overall well-being. These virtues include things like generosity, compassion, and mindfulness. When we act in accordance with skillful virtues, we cultivate inner peace and harmony with others.
The opposite of these virtues—actions driven by greed, hatred, or delusion—are considered unskillful ("akusala"). These actions lead to remorse for several reasons:

Mental Agitation and Inner Conflict: Unskillful actions often create inner conflict because they go against the natural inclination toward goodness. The mind, which thrives on peace and clarity, becomes disturbed when we act out of selfishness or harm. This disturbance results in feelings of guilt or regret, as we realize our actions are misaligned with our deeper values.

Harm to Others and Self: Unskillful actions can cause harm to others and even to ourselves. When we realize the negative impact of our actions, feelings of remorse naturally arise. This remorse is the mind's way of signaling that something was wrong, urging us to correct our behavior in the future.

Karmic Consequences: According to the law of karma, unskillful actions generate negative consequences. Remorse may arise as an intuitive awareness of these future repercussions. While these consequences might not be immediate, they often weigh on the conscience.

Loss of Integrity: Acting against virtuous qualities erodes one's sense of integrity and moral standing. When we compromise our values, we feel remorse because we know we've betrayed an essential part of ourselves.


In essence, remorse following unskillful actions serves as a form of feedback, guiding us back toward a path of virtue and mindfulness. It's a reminder to be more aware of how our actions affect both our inner world and the people around us.
